# SQL Server Replication - How to connect to a system via computer name rather than IP address in Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, database-replication

In Amazon AWS, VPC, I am trying to setup replication in SQL Server, and have three servers setup with port 1433 RDP open (1 web, two SQL).  I can RDC into each server.  From the web server, I can connect via SSMS to both SQL Servers by using the IP address.  However, I am unable to connect to them with their server names.  This wouldn't normally be an issue but in trying to setup a replication subscriber, I cannot use the IP address and have to use the server name, and receive the following error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to 10.0.2.xxx.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other alternate name are not supported. Specify the actual server name, 'xxxxxxxxxx'. (Replication.Utilities)

------------------------------
```

In my security group settings (I have both SQL Server's in one group), I opened up all ports, but still don't see server B in the list of available network servers from server A.

I also have *enable remote connections* enabled.

How can I resolve this?

**-- UPDATE --**

I have tried several of the suggestions provided [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic554399-149-2.aspx#bm1512504), but am still experiencing the same issue.

In short, on server A, I created an alias in my hosts file pointing to server B.
In SQL Server config manager, I created an alias, pointing to the name I created in the hosts file.  On server A, in SSMS, I then connect to db server B using the alias I put in the SQL Server config manager - so I know that alias worked.

However, when I enter that alias name in trying to setup a subscriber, I get the same error as earlier.